# How do I concisely end print() with a double new line?

Tags: python-3.x

In an attempt to format my output nicely (since it is turned in as part of an assignment), I like to follow each `print(...)` call with a second `print()` to create a line break before the next item to be printed. Is there a way to condense this down to a single line? Thank you very much!

***What I do presently:***

```py
a = 10

b = 20

print("a =", a)

print()

print("b =", b)

print()
```

***The kind of thing I am looking for:***

```py
print("a =", a, doubleNewLine)

print("b =", b, doubleNewLine)
```

Comment: `print(a =", a, "\n")` will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, what you've originally proposed in the question as "the kind of thing I am looking for" is actually working:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> doubleNewLine = "\n"*2
>>> print("a =", a, doubleNewLine)
a = 1 


>>>
```

More concisely:

```
print("a =", a, end="\n\n")
```

Comment: Thank you very much! So is there any real difference between using print("a =", a, end="\n\n") and print(a =", a, "\n") ? I see what end= performs, but I will definitely be using the _second_ option moving forward for efficiency in this particular situation.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the first method shown in the answer is just sending extra new line(s) as an additional argument to print, which means the newline(s) will be preceded by an extra space character.  For this reason the second option, specifying `end`, is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

use the `\n` end character. That skips one line when you print something.